# Clean and reset table in mvc 4 Web application

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008

I am wanting to delete all data from a table and reset the id column to 1. I want to do this in my controller, but i want to know the best way to do that. I have tried the SQLConnection/SQLCommand route, but have been unable to connect to the database successfully to do that. Is there a way like running a db.Clean function or something like that?

**Updated**
Here is how far it gets in the code:

```
 string connectionString = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=c:\\Webs\\MvcFFL\\MvcFFL\\App_Data\\Players.mdf;Integrated Security=True";

    string queryString =  "Truncate table Players;";
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);

    connection.Open(); <- Fails here opening the connection
}
```

Then when it hits the connection.Open() here is the error:

> An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code Additional information: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

What can i do instead of this method?

Comment: You're going to have to connect to the database before you can run any commands against it.  Perhaps you could post some details about the problems you're having connecting to the database?

Comment: I have update my post see above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an unescaped `\`in `(LocalDB)\v11.0`

You can change it to `(LocalDB)\\v11.0`, or else change the whole connection string to
`@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=c:\Webs\MvcFFL\MvcFFL\App_Data\Players.mdf;Integrated Security=True"` (notice the `@` and the lack of `\\`)